# Reading merged cells with ADO

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet like so:

```
1 CONTRACT   AMOUNT   AGENT   COMMISSION
2 ========================================
3                      AG1       15.00
4 20-123      300      AG2       15.00
5                      AG3       15.00
..........................................
6                      AG4       25.00
7 20-234      500      AG2       25.00
8                      AG5       21.00
```

The first two columns are merged for common CONTRACTS ie, in both contracts the same contract and total amount applies to all three agents

I'm trying to read the data with ADO:

```
Select * from [Sheet1$A1:D8] WHERE ISNUMERIC(LEFT([CONTRACT],2)) ORDER BY [Agent]
```

Unfortunately from the above example only two record are returned - those for rows 3 and 6. It seems that as far as ADO is concerned, only the first cell in the merged range contains data.

If I unmerge the first two columns, and list the duplicate contract and amount info next to each agent, then the sum of my amounts will be incorrect at 2400.00 instead of 800.00, and it won't be as visually appealing (It's used as a report)

Is there a way for ADO to apply the contents of a merged cells to each row?

Comment: I think you'll have to re-work your approach.  ADO is really designed to work with "regular" data from databases or other data sources - it doesn't really "know" about merged cells.

Comment: BTW: It's not just ADO that sees the value only in the first cell--that's how it is stored natively in Excel.